# Zurb Foundation - orbit slider - images don't take full width

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, orbit

I'm having troubles with orbit, the image slider. I have it take only half of the row (there will be text next to it), so my code is following:

```
<div="row">
<div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">

            <div class="orbit" role="region" aria-label="" data-orbit>
              <ul class="orbit-container">

                <button class="orbit-previous"><span class="show-for-sr">Previous Slide</span>&#9664;&#xFE0E;</button>
                <button class="orbit-next"><span class="show-for-sr">Next Slide</span>&#9654;&#xFE0E;</button>

                <li class="is-active orbit-slide">
                  <img class="orbit-image" src="assets/exteriery/img-02.jpg" alt="">
                </li>               

                <li class="orbit-slide">
                  <img class="orbit-image" src="assets/exteriery/img-06.jpg" alt="">
                </li>

                <li class="orbit-slide">
                  <img class="orbit-image" src="assets/exteriery/img-11.jpg" alt="">
                </li>
              </ul>
              <nav class="orbit-bullets">
                <button class="is-active" data-slide="0"><span class="show-for-sr">First slide details.</span><span class="show-for-sr">Current Slide</span></button>
                <button data-slide="1"><span class="show-for-sr">Second slide details.</span></button>
                <button data-slide="2"><span class="show-for-sr">Third slide details.</span></button>
                <button data-slide="3"><span class="show-for-sr">Fourth slide details.</span></button>
                <button data-slide="4"><span class="show-for-sr">Fifth slide details.</span></button>
                <button data-slide="5"><span class="show-for-sr">Sixth slide details.</span></button>

              </nav>
            </div> <!-- orbit -->
          </div> <!-- -->

<div class="small-12 medium-6 columns"></div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is that the images don't take the full size of the orbit container.   This is what it looks like:
`.orbit` has red border.
`.orbit-container` has a green border and yellow background.
I have not styled `.orbit` or `.orbit-container` in any other way.

[image: orbit]

As the image shows, the image does not take the full width of `.orbit`, which makes the arrows not centred as well. I have tried to play with different widths, paddings, margins, but nothing seems to work. Even when I give the `.orbit` a specific width (I tried 650px), there was still the gap on the right. The images are large enough (this specific one is 3264px x 2448px), and I have not styled the image in any other way in my css.

What do I need to do to fix this?
Thank you.

EDIT:
I have created a CodePen pen and it works well there... [CodePen example](https://codepen.io/FairyCodeMother/pen/VpXNGa?editors=1010). Not sure what I did and where, will try to re-write the section again and find the bug.

Comment: Please post a working example.

Comment: What do you mean, a working example? I posted my code and the image. I have nothing else to show.

Comment: I meant a working fiddle/plunker/codepen snippet so I can actually see whats happening in the slider.

Comment: Ok, I will need to prepare this so I'll post back when it's done. Sorry about that.

Comment: It works well on CodePen (link inserted above). Not sure what I did and where that it doesn't work on my local website :/

Comment: Send pls link to your website.

Comment: It's not live yet, I'm still developing it.

Comment: Can you try to upload it pls? i need to look the real dev

Comment: Since the code is working on CodePen, I'm going to re-do my code again, maybe I miss-typed something somewhere. I'll will report back tomorrow.

Comment: Try `.orbit-slide img { width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }`

Comment: did you try to put your image in the codepen example?

Comment: Gavin, this did not work.

Comment: Sahil, no, I used images from http://placehold.it. I don't have my images hosted anywhere online yet, couldn't link to them. I'm still trying to figure out where I went wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this (except on the left of the image), and it was because I had padding applied to this element:

```
<ul class="orbit-container">
```

So this css should fix it:

```
ul.orbit-container {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```